# Dll getting loaded but load library is giving the error code 5 and GetProcAddress is also generating the same error code 5

Tags: c++, dll

when i try to load the dll it is getting loaded but the load library is giving the error code 5 and GetProcAddress is also generating the same error code 5. when i searched in google i found the following links

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142814

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Any idea on what does the error is actually.....

Here is my code

```
typedef int (WINAPI *PFNREGDELETEVALUE)(HKEY,LPCSTR);

int main()
{

int a;
PFNREGDELETEVALUE pfnRegOpenKeyEx = NULL;
    DWORD ret2 = GetLastError();
    cout << ret2 << "\n";
HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\bmisc60e.dll");
    DWORD ret1 = GetLastError();
    cout << ret1 << "\n";
if(h==NULL)
cout << "error"; 
    pfnRegOpenKeyEx = 
    (PFNREGDELETEVALUE)GetProcAddress(h,"@RegDeleteValue32$qqsp6HKEY__pxc");                                                                                                   

if(pfnRegOpenKeyEx != NULL)
    {
    cout << "success";
    DWORD ret = GetLastError();
    cout << ret;

    }
cin >> a;
return 0;
    }
```

the output of the above code is
0
5
success 
5

Thanks in Advance........

Comment: Error 5 is [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I wouldn't expect `GetProcAddress()` to ever return that, but `LoadLibrary()` certainly could if you don't have read or execute permissions to the DLL file.  Are you *sure* that `LoadLibrary()` is succeeding?

Comment: You shouldn't continue if you get an error in LoadLibrary.  Does this library have any dependencies?  Are all the dependencies on %path%?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield  Yes i am very much sure that the dll is loaded.

Comment: @cup i have checked with other function it is getting loaded and executed correctly.it does not have any dependencies.

Comment: Your DLL is not being loaded: it is returning ACCESS_DENIED (first 5).  Check access with cacls from the cmd prompt.  If it is incorrect, change it using cacls (or whatever your OS equivalent is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [LoadLibrary doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),

> **Return Value**:: If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get
>   extended error information, call GetLastError.

You should not check for `GetLastError()` if the above mentioned return value is not returned by the API. This is because, some other API would have `SetLastError()` to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5)` and you are collecting that now.

This would be more correct code::

```
typedef int (WINAPI *PFNREGDELETEVALUE)(HKEY,LPCSTR);

int main()
{
 int a;
 DWORD dwRet = 0;
 PFNREGDELETEVALUE pfnRegOpenKeyEx = NULL;

 HMODULE h = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\bmisc60e.dll");
 if(h==NULL)
 {
  dwRet = GetLastError() ;
  cout << "LoadLibrary Error = ";
  cout << dwRet ;
  return -1 ;
 }

 pfnRegOpenKeyEx = (PFNREGDELETEVALUE)GetProcAddress(h,"@RegDeleteValue32$qqsp6HKEY__pxc");                                                                                                   
 if(pfnRegOpenKeyEx == NULL)
 {
  dwRet = GetLastError() ;
  cout << "LoadLibrary Error = ";
  cout << dwRet ;
  FreeLibrary(h) ; // Optional
  return -1 ;
 }

 cout << "Success" ;
 cin >> a;
 return 0;
}
```